# Why am I getting ' $ is undefined'?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've working on a Wordpress site and starting on some simple sqripts:

```
(function () {
    // Flex
    if ($(".flexslider").length) {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I've also tried

```
$(function () {
    // Flex
    if ($(".flexslider").length) {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider();
    }
});
```

jQuery is running, so why isn't `$` recognized? If I replace `$` with `jQuery` it works fine.

This also isn't working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('.section_header').click(function(){
        alert('test');
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have some source code to look at?

Comment: Are you using some other libraries, like prototype.js?

Comment: Yes, it's the above code.... I only use jQuery.

Comment: You need to pass in the $ alias to the first function.

Comment: gimie a link to the page i can tell you exactly what's wrong

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery before your plugin?

Comment: This is because if I recall correctly jQuery by default runs in No-Conflict mode within WP - you have to do as I suggest and as Connors answer suggests which is to IIFE and pass in the alias.

Comment: @rlemon - I tried that. The error goes away, but no jQuery functions trigger. This is annoying. I've been using jQuery for a few years now, and suddenly I get this.

Comment: @Steven, Then that is a separate issue which can be dealt with. For what it is worth, WP forcing noConflict is kind of stupid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   (function ($) {
        // Flex
        if ($(".flexslider").length) {
            $('.flexslider').flexslider();
        }
    })(jQuery);
```

Try this

The top param is the one to be used as a reference to the bottom one

so for example you could do this

```
(function (somethingHereCool) {
    // Flex
    if (somethingHereCool(".flexslider").length) {
        somethingHereCool('.flexslider').flexslider();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The reason this happens (mostly in wordpress) is because wordpress uses jQuery's `$.noConflict()`
By Defualt

so this basically means that `$` doesn't belong to jQuery anymore so you can do it like above and redefine the $ in that scope for you to use. Your basically copying jQuery and giving it to $

Comment: See my updated question. The traditional jQuery function isn't working either.

Comment: I tested using `($)`, but that doesn't work. I don't get any errors, but the jQuery isn't triggered.

Comment: It is important to know that the version of jQuery that comes with WordPress automatically calls the jQuery.noConflict(); function. Like I have mentioned now a few times.....

Comment: @rlemon - Any way of preventing `jQuery.noConflict();` being called?

Comment: ok, thanks for the info and help. I got it working now. You don't need the `(jQuery)` at the end of the function.

Comment: Correcting myself here: You don't need the jQuery at the bottom if you start with `jQuery(function($)`.

Comment: Yes that is becuase `jQuery(...);` is totally different

Answer (score 0):

the $ has a different meaning/function in jQuery. I have noticed the same while making jQueries in my .jsp files. I am not sure what the $ is designed to be, but I use jQuery in the dollars place

Comment: like many libraries, the $ is used as an [uninformative variable name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting)

Comment: `$`is the shorthand for `jQuery`. But it can cause problems if you are using different libraries. That's why using `jQuery` is better. But using `$` saves characters...

Comment: Yeah, I learned that the $ is a jstl variable definer, and since you can use jQuery within a jsp file, it must be declared using jQuery instead of the $, which already has a different function. I believe that if you are using it in a wordpress site which uses html/jsp or similar, the dollar has a different meaning

Comment: Using jQuery in my jsp files tought me that i cannot use the 'jQuery(document).ready(function() {' only makes the jQueries not work. So remove it entirely and only have '<script type="text/javascript">' in the start. After this, just create all the 'jQuery(function(){' you need. This works for me

Answer (score 0):

There's also a nonConflict option for jQuery (see: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/ ). If nonConflict is defined the $ won't be recognized.

EDIT: Besides that, if "jQuery(document).ready(function() {" isn't working either I don't think jQuery is actually linked correctly (or before you do anything).

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me in Wordpress

```
jQuery(function($) {
//code in here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to what [Connor said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17488597/535122), which basically is that you need to pass the `$` as parameter to the function, in order to use the `$` as `jQuery`.

The reason it isn't so by default, is because jQuery offers an option to [disable](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) `$`. This is mostly used when you are using a different JS framework which uses its own implementation of the `$` variable, so no conflict would arise.

To disable jQuery from using `$`. You need to write the following, preferably directly after importing the jQuery library. Which should also be imported before importing any other framework.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment: By the way - its "Connor" :)